# How to return true if x data exists in JSON or CSV from API on Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, api, nft

is there any easy method to call APIs from Wordpress website and return true or false, depends if some data is there?

Here is the API:

```
https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/137/address/0x3FEb1D627c96cD918f2E554A803210DA09084462/balances_v2/?&format=JSON&nft=true&no-nft-fetch=true&key=ckey_docs
```

here is a JSON:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "address": "0x3feb1d627c96cd918f2e554a803210da09084462",
    "updated_at": "2021-11-13T23:25:27.639021367Z",
    "next_update_at": "2021-11-13T23:30:27.639021727Z",
    "quote_currency": "USD",
    "chain_id": 137,
    "items": [
      {
        "contract_decimals": 0,
        "contract_name": "PublicServiceKoalas",
        "contract_ticker_symbol": "PSK",
        "contract_address": "0xc5df71db9055e6e1d9a37a86411fd6189ca2dbbb",
        "supports_erc": [
          "erc20"
        ],
        "logo_url": "https://logos.covalenthq.com/tokens/137/0xc5df71db9055e6e1d9a37a86411fd6189ca2dbbb.png",
        "last_transferred_at": "2021-11-13T09:45:36Z",
        "type": "nft",
        "balance": "0",
        "balance_24h": null,
        "quote_rate": 0.0,
        "quote_rate_24h": null,
        "quote": 0.0,
        "quote_24h": null,
        "nft_data": null
      }
    ],
    "pagination": null
  },
  "error": false,
  "error_message": null,
  "error_code": null
}
```

I want to check if there is "PSK" in contract_ticker_symbol, if it exist and "balance" is > 0 ... then return true.

Is there any painless method because I'm not a programmer...

Answer (score 0):

The Python requests library can handle this. You'll have to install it with pip first (package installer for Python).

I also used a website called [JSON Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr) to see what was going on with all of the data first so that I would be able to make sense of it in my code:

```py
import requests

def main():
    url = "https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/137/address/0x3FEb1D627c96cD918f2E554A803210DA09084462/balances_v2/?&format" \
          "=JSON&nft=true&no-nft-fetch=true&key=ckey_docs "
    try:
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        for item in response['data']['items']:
            # First, find 'PSK' in the list
            if item['contract_ticker_symbol'] == "PSK":
                # Now, check the balance
                if item['balance'] == 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Exception")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

This is what is going on:

1. I am pulling all of the data from the API.
2. I am using a try/except clause because I need the code to
   handle if I can't make a connection to the site.
3. I am looping through all of the 'items' to find the correct 'item'
   that includes the contract ticker symbol for 'PSK'.
4. I am checking the balance in that item and returning the logic that you wanted.
5. The script is running itself at the end, but you can always just rename this function and have some other code call it to check it.

Comment: Do you know how it can be integrated into a Wordpress website? because I'm not really sure...

Comment: You'd have to use PHP because that is what Wordpress is based off of code wise. From what I am reading, people generally just make their own packages to call APIs. I would search for that.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to find direct answer but can't find anything really useful.. xD